# How to rename an alias in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, alias

I want to make my own versions of some of the builtin PowerShell aliases.  Rather than completely removing the overridden aliases, I'd like to rename them so I can still use them if I want to.  For example, maybe I'll rename `set` to `orig_set` and then add my own new definition for `set`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
PS> alias *set*

CommandType     Name     Definition
-----------     ----     ----------
Alias           set      Set-Variable

PS> function Rename-Alias( $s0, $s1 ) { Rename-Item Alias:\$s0 $s1 -Force }
PS> Rename-Alias set orig_set
PS> alias *set*

CommandType     Name     Definition
-----------     ----     ----------
Alias           set      Set-Variable
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: I can't explain it right now but if you execute your rename-alias function in the current scope it works (at least when the current scope is the global scope) e.g. `. Rename-Alias set orig_set`.

Comment: @Keith Hill, hmm, I've tried this on several machines.  I mainly define Rename-Alias in my profile script but even defining the function at the command line always results in the same behavior: the `set` alias is not renamed.  I'm using PowerShell 2, does that matter?  I'm using RemoteSigned execution, does that matter?

Comment: The trick isn't where you "define" the function but which scope it runs in.  When you preface a command with a `.` you are dot sourcing it.  That is, it runs as if you executed the body of the function in the current scope.  BTW I'm running v2 also with policy set to RemoteSigned.

Comment: @Keith, I'm still not getting it.  I will edit my question to hopefully make it better.  Do you get the same results as me if you paste into your PowerShell?

Comment: @Keith, I get the 'dot' part.  How do I do the equivalent inside a function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One solution: change how you call the Rename-Alias function.  Instead of

`PS> Rename-Alias set orig_set`

do this:

`PS> . Rename-Alias set orig_set`

*[Thanks to @Keith Hill for this tip.]*

But this begs the question: how can one write a function to rename aliases without needing to always be called with dot (.)?

Answer (score 3):

The beauty of the provider system in PowerShell is that you can use good ol' `Rename-Item` on alias because there is an alias drive e.g:

```
Rename-Item Alias:\set original_set -Force
```

That is, you learn how to use Get-ChildItem, Remove-Item, Copy-Item, etc and you can apply them to things other than directories and files - as long as the "thing" is contained in a provider.  To see all your providers execute:

```
Get-PSProvider
```

To see all the drives created from these providers execute:

```
Get-PSDrive
```

Comment: your syntax works great interactively but when I use it a function (see my edited question) it fails ('set' is not renamed).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
function Rename-Alias($old, $new)
{
    $resolved = get-alias $old
    $cmdletName = $resolved.definition
    Set-Alias $new $cmdletname
    rm "alias:\$old" -force
}
```

Comment: @joey: sorry, forgot that's not the way to remove an alias.  you remove it from  the alias psdrive

Comment: Well, see my answer, `Remove-Item` apparently cannot remove the built-in aliases.

Comment: @joey: just add -force onto the end

Comment: Ouch, sorry. That's one of the arguments I constantly forget. Disregard my complaints, then :-)

Comment: @Joey: I'm not confident this is perfectly working but I don't have time ATM to make sure.  However I think this is headed in the right direction.

Comment: Well, this should work fine enough, I guess. I was heading in a similar direction but after `Rename-Item` and `Remove-Item` didn't work, I gave up. You can shorten your function to `function Rename-Alias ($Name, $NewName) { Rename-Item Alias:$Name Alias:$NewName -Force }` though (also using standard parameter names). You avoid copying the definition, then since rename just stopped at the read-only-ness as did the remove.

Comment: I edited my original post to add a test.  The current version of Rename-Alias in this answer doesn't pass the test.  There are no errors either.

Comment: @Joey, I tried your suggested one-liner but it also fails the test: the "set" alias remains exactly the same.  Its name is still "set".